# Override CSS of Vue Component once it has been loaded in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am working on a page and I need to override the CSS of a Vue component that has been loaded in the browser and created by another developer.

Is there a way of overriding the CSS of the Vue component after page load.

I've tried the following:

- using the !important tag
- trying to increase css specificity
- using the :host() & :root() selectors to try and override the component css

However none appear to work and it appears that the component also generates a style="" in the tags so the CSS is embedded at that level within each tag.

Just wondering is there any way of applying CSS in the base HTML file that would override the CSS of the component.

Thanks for any help with this.